# how to upload site to the server

Tags: file-upload, filezilla, publishing-site

I have a question....I'm using FileZilla to upload my eclipse project to the server. Now, it's the first time I do that and I don't know where to start. (I really don't want to do disasters)
in this image there is the composition of folders: on the left there is my project and on the right there is the server's folders.
http://img22.imageshack.us/img22/2519/jbecagca.png
In the folder WebContent I have also my 4 html files and one of these is index.html that is the page that has to be shown when I write the url of the site.
Now the question is... Where do I have to put my servlets? where my classes? where my sql dump of my database? where my html pages? where my js files? 
I really have no idea.
thanks for any help!!

Answer (score 0):

Go to your web host ask address for sql database you need to make a database on any of their server then it can be used you cant just use by uploading .
js files and classes will be used same hierarchy you used time of development.

Comment: I can't understand how to upload the database. Is there any guide?

Comment: generate a script of database and run of the host side database you can not upload the file just script can be run on host side.

Comment: I don't understand... I've my dump.sql that is the backup of my db. Now what I have to do with this file?

Comment: use thse backup file in any database open in the database manager once you have opende database http://www.sqlscriptgenerator.com/ can be used to generate script and then run that script of host database.using script manager etc

Answer (score 0):

If you're uploading a project, you should probably keep the project's folder structure. You should upload the whole project folder as is to the webroot, so you can access it from your browser

Comment: yes I have to keep the  project's folder structure. Can I create a War?